# Appending to file internal storage android

Tags: android, file-io, internal-storage

If you have an existing file in the internal storage in the android app, how do you append a string to the file? I have tried using FileOutPutStream.write() but that just seems to overwrite the whole file and causes the previous data to be lost.

Comment: Use either the `FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)` or `FileOutputStream(String path, boolean append)` constructor when creating your `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: At the moment i have FileOutputStream outputstream = openFileOutput(projectDate, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); where projectDate is the filename. If i use that constructor, will it still know to go to the internal storage?

Comment: Use `getFilesDir()` to get the directory where files using `openFileInput(...)` and `openFileOutput(...)` are stored. You can then construct an absolute path to the file and pass it to the `FileOutputStream(String path, boolean append)` constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by Squonk, you can manually create your FileOutputStream in append mode with:

```
FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)
FileOutputStream(String path, boolean append)
```

Or alternatively and arguably preferably, by using the native android method:

```
openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
```

Which opens a file named 'FILENAME' located in the default storage location for your app.  It is usually best to let the OS decide where to store your files. [Details on storage options here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal). It describes how to access each of the standard storage locations and methods. Which one you choose depends on what it is you are trying to store.

Comment: Ah yes. I'd forgotten about `Context.MODE_APPEND`. A much better way of doing it for the OP's current approach.

Comment: By default storage location, do you mean the internal storage? Sorry if it seems a stupid question, new to storage in Android

Comment: Yes, in this case it should save to the internal storage. The caveat being if that is the default location in the ROM installed. Each device and ROM defines these locations differently depending on hardware available and the implementation of available storage types. Read the link I included in my answer for more in depth details and the suggested way to handle your app's storage requirements in general. The beauty of using those native methods is that you don't need to care where things get saved as how you access those resources will work regardless of the ROM's implementation.

Comment: ... and all you need to worry about is using the correct type of native method for your use case. Use the cache for short lived storage, the "external directory" for large files, default/internal for small files you want to persist or need quick read/write access to, use databases where they fit your model etc.

Comment: @indivisible : Just to add to the 'location' of storage. With more recent devices the difference between internal and external is becoming increasingly blurred. My Nexus 7 (for example) doesn't have an SD card (traditionally the external storage). Instead it has 8GB of physically 'internal' storage which is partitioned into areas for  private (what we normally refer to as 'internal' storage) and public (equivalent to SD card). As you say though, using the native helper methods rather than hard-coded paths means not having to worry about the actual location of files.

Comment: @Squonk, Exactly. Let the OS decide _where_ to put it, you need only concern yourself with deciding _what_ it is to allow you to select the correct method to use.